# calling exe on server from asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

want to run exe from asp.net on my server, is this possible?

I use this method:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    // Set the directory where the file resides

    process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\dev\Analyzer\bin\Release";
    // Set the filename name of the file you want to open

    process1.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\dev\Analyzer\bin\Release\Analyzer.exe";
    process1.StartInfo.Arguments = "123";
    // Start the process

    process1.Start();
```

it works when i debug it, but when put my website on localhost then i have exception:

> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\dq'

where dq is name of my website.

Stack:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\dq'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser user) at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() at Analyzer.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\dev\Analyzer\Program.cs:line 59

Comment: Please provide the full exception details. Saying an exception was thrown is useless without the details.

Comment: What useraccount does the website use and does it have access to these files?

Comment: Also it requires certain .net permissions wich might not be granted on most hosts.

Comment: What line are you getting this exception on? It has nothing to do with the code you posted, unless this is thrown by your `analyser.exe`.

Comment: And what it the exception? I am assuming that the `TdsParser` is choking on the SQL.

Comment: ok what property of exception e whould i put into log u r interresting for?

Comment: yee he is trying to retrive some data from Db, you r right that process start but then it has no acces to db, connection string looks like this: <add name="AnalyzerConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxxx"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming here that the exception you are getting is an access violation one.

If that is the case, you need to ensure to either start the process with a `UserName` and `Password` for an account with enough privileges to run the executable (and access the directory it is in), or setup the application pool with such an account.

---

Update:

The stack trace points at a bad LINQ query, not `Process.Start`. What exactly is the exception? I can't tell from the trace.

What line is this throwing on?

---

Update 2:

Check your connection strings and SQL Server - the site account is failing to login to SQL Server. This has absolutely nothing to do with `Process.Start` or LINQ syntax.

Have you set the correct password? If you are using integrated security (`SSPI=true`), have you ensured that SQL Server has this login enabled?

Comment: how can i 'start the process with a UserName and Password for an account with enough privileges' from asp?

Comment: @kosnkov - You use the `UserName` and `Password` properties of the `Process.StartInfo` property of the process object, supplying the credentials of an account that has enough privileges.

Comment: exception is  Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\dq'

Comment: @kosnkov - Then your web application is failing to login to SQL Server. Are the connection strings OK? Are the accounts setup correctly on SQL Server?

Comment: it worsk when i click on this analyzer.exe, but running as procesess from asp throw this sql exception. what can i do?

Comment: @kosnkov - You run `analyser.exe` on the server and it runs fine, but not when you run it from the web application through `Process.Start`? Are you _certain_ that you are pointing to the same directory?

Comment: to be honest i didn't change anything yet, but i have my website openend in visual and put on localhost, all is fine when i run this analyzer clicking on it, it also works if my website opened in visual run it, but it fail with this exception when i put my website localy on iis and then try to run it.

Comment: @kosnkov - Do you have other connection strings? In the web application? In particular any with `SSPI=true` in them? I suspect the connection string you posted is not the problem. When asked for the connection strings, please post _all_ of them.

Comment: ok problem solved, you were right, application was using different connection with Integrated Security=True", first i didn't know that, so i changed identitiy of application pool under IIS, and then it worked, then u helped me, i added user and pass to connection string and now it works with identity set to applicationPoolIdentity so thanks a lot.

Comment: @kosnkov - In that case, I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Oded u helped me, problem solved, look one message above. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not recommended at all. On server, your ASP.NET website also runs as a process. 
Launching another process would require some extra permissions. Worker process is trying to launch analyzer.exe with its own user's (IIS APPPOOL\dq) account and is failing there. You would require to run your worker process with another account which will have enough permissions to launch another executable.

BTW, this will open up your surface area for threats. Not recommended at all.

Thanks
Gaurav